# Как передать маршрут или массив POI в Яндекс Навигатор (Андроид и Ios)?

Tags: яндекс-карты, route

или может это возможно для других навигаторов?

Answer (score 0):

Все оказывается просто. 
После формирования маршрута внизу слева появляется ссылка "открыть в картах"
По клику на ней появляется предложение установить приложение "яндекс карты" где и возможна навигация по этому маршруту.
А если в настройках карты поставить галочку "открывать маршруты  в Яндекс навигаторе" то маршрут сразу передается в яндекс навигатор